# question mark colon switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement, conditional-operator

```
public Boolean prendiTessera(TipoTerreno tipo) {
    
    switch(tipo){
    
    case PIANURA: tesserePianura != 4 ? tesserePianura++ : return false;

    case CAMPAGNA: tessereCampagna != 4 ? tessereCampagna++ : return false;
    
    case MONTAGNA: tessereMontagna != 4 ? tessereMontagna++ : return false;
    
    case DESERTO: tessereDeserto != 4 ? tessereDeserto++ : return false;
    
    case FIUME: tessereFiume != 4 ? tessereFiume++ : return false;
    
    case BOSCO: tessereBosco != 4 ? tessereBosco++ : return false;
    
    default: return false;  
    }
    
    return true;
    
}
```

Eclipse reports the following errors (for each line):

> Syntax error on token "!=", invalid AssignmentOperator
>
> Syntax error on token "return", delete this token
>
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int

Variables:

> private int tesserePianura;
>
> private int tessereCampagna;
>
> private int tessereMontagna;
>
> private int tessereDeserto;
>
> private int tessereFiume;
>
> private int tessereBosco;

Enum Class:

```
public enum TipoTerreno {

/** terreno pianura. */
PIANURA,

/** terreno campagna. */
CAMPAGNA,

/** terreno montagna. */
MONTAGNA,

/** terreno deserto. */
DESERTO,

/** terreno fiume. */
FIUME,

/** terreno bosco. */
BOSCO,

/** terreno Sheepsburg. */
SHEEPSBURG;
        
}
```

Comment: The `ternary operator` is not a statement (like if/else), but rather an expression.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, The problem is not the ternary operator.  An expression _is_ a statement if it appears where a statement is expected.  The problem is the 'return'.  'return' is a statement, but it appears here where an expression is wanted (i.e., as the third arg of the ternary.

Comment: @jameslarge An expression evaluates to a value. You're right, the `return` is the problem since it itself _is_ a statement and doesn't evaluate to a value, which is required for the last part of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this and your problem is sorted

```
public Boolean prendiTessera(TipoTerreno tipo) {
    boolean flag=true;
    switch (tipo) {

        case PIANURA: flag=tesserePianura != 4 ? true :false; break;

        case CAMPAGNA: flag=tessereCampagna != 4 ? true : false;break;

        case MONTAGNA: flag=tessereMontagna != 4 ? true : false;break;

        case DESERTO: flag=tessereDeserto != 4 ? true : false;break;

        case FIUME: flag=tessereFiume != 4 ? true : false;break;

        case BOSCO: flag=tessereBosco != 4 ? true : false;break;

        default: flag=false;  
    }
    if (flag)
        tessereMontagna++;
    return flag;
}
```

**Problem description:**

```
tesserePianura != 4 ? tesserePianura++ : return false;
```

Your this line isn't a complete statement, that's why you were getting error.
And your else part/last part is a complete statement which can't come in expression (i.e., ternary operator).

Moreover ternary operator are meant to produce some result that to be assigned to some variable **directly** or **indirectly**.

Let me explain this to you
**direct assignment**

```
flag=tessereBosco != 4 ? true : false;
```

in this case value is directly assigned to variable `flag`.

**indirect assignment**

```
System.out.println(tessereBosco != 4 ? true : false);
```

in this case assignment to function's ( i.e., `println()` ) variable will be made.

Comment: This may compile, but the OP apparently also wants the side-effect of, for example, `tesserePianura++` in the first case.

Comment: I didn't get to see OP asking for side effect of this? ofcourse that would be my mistake, would you mind pointing me towards it @GriffeyDog

Comment: The first `case`, for instance: `case PIANURA: tesserePianura != 4 ? tesserePianura++ : return false;`

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest way to correct that using  ternary operator

```
public Boolean prendiTessera(TipoTerreno tipo) {
    int test;

    switch(tipo){

        case PIANURA: test= ( tesserePianura != 4) ? tesserePianura++ : 0; break;

        case CAMPAGNA: test=( tessereCampagna != 4) ? tessereCampagna++ : 0;break;

        case MONTAGNA: test=  (tessereMontagna != 4) ? tessereMontagna++ : 0;break;

        case DESERTO: test= (tessereDeserto != 4) ? tessereDeserto++ :0;break;

        case FIUME: test= (tessereFiume != 4) ? tessereFiume++ : 0;break;

        case BOSCO:test=  (tessereBosco != 4) ? tessereBosco++ :0;break;

        default: test=0;  
    }

    return (test==1);

}
```